# Regular expression for hexadecimal string in python not working

Tags: python, regex, hex

I have a regular expression to match strings like:

> --D2CBA65440D
>
> --77094A27E09
>
> --77094A27E
>
> --770
>
> --77094A27E09--

basically, it matches a hexadecimal string surrounded by one or more line breaks or white space, and has the prefix -- and may or may not have -- as suffix

i use the following python code, and it works fine most of the time:

```
hexaPattern = "\s--[0-9a-fA-F]+[--]?\s"
hex = re.search(hexaPattern, part)
if hex:
   print "found a match"
```

this works for all of the above but it doesn't match --77094A27E09 in this block:

```
<div id="arrow2" class="headerLinksImg" style="display:block

--77094A27E09

;">
```

but matches the same string in:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkboxKG3" class

--77094A27E09

Content-T="checkboxKG" value="KG3" />
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: try trimming down the html on either side until you find the character that's causing the problem

Comment: I get a match for that block: http://rubular.com/r/wfqgEPHObB

Comment: Note that `[--]?` will match one or none dashes, *not* two dashes. I think you meant `(--)?`

Comment: i meant two dashes ... but `[--]?` worked

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used the following :

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\n--)([0-9A-F]+)(--)?', re.I | re.S | re.M)
```

and it worked fine. Thanks to all your contributions.

Comment: Just, FYI, this wouldn't match the pattern if it's at the start of a buffer. Using `^` as Israel mentioned would work to find it at the start of any line.

Answer (score 12):

```
import re
hexaPattern = re.compile(r'\s--([0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:--)?\s')
m = re.search(hexaPattern, part)
if m:
   print "found a match:", m.group(1)
```

This pre-compiles the pattern for speed.  This uses a `r''` (raw string) so the backslashes are sure to be passed through correctly.  This adds parentheses to make a "match group" so you can extract your hex string after the match; it also adds a "non-matching group" around the second `--` string.

Because you used the square brackets around the second "--", you got a "character class".  I'm not sure exactly what the character class `[--]` matches; I think it should just match any `'-'` character.  In a character class, a '-' is usually used for a range, as in `[a-z]` but the range `[--]` makes no sense so I think it would fall back to just matching a `'-'`.  The problem is: because you have the `?` after it, it would only match zero or one `'-'` character, and you need it to be able to match two.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you only need to compile the pattern if you're using a lot of different patterns.  According to [python re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile), these values are cached, so if you're using just a few patterns, compiling them won't do you much.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
`hexaPattern = r"^--[0-9a-fA-F]+(--)?\s"`

The fixes I inserted are:

r at the beginning, so that that backslashes won't be "eaten" by the quotation marks

^ at the beginning to match the start of the string

then `--` in parenthesis instead of square brackets (the brackets seem like a mistake)

Comment: You don't want to match from the beginning. OP's hex values are embedded in a longer string of html.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out problems with your regex, namely the `[--]` which basically finds one single hyphen in an unconventional way ... either way, not what you want anyway.

I would also suggest that having `\s` at both the beginning and end of the regex will also cause problems under certain circumstances, because it matches `spaces`, `tabs`, and `newlines`. So you could end up with a case where your file has `--77094A27E09\n--D2CBA65440D` and the second `--D2CBA65440D` won't match because the newline was consumed by `\s` at the end of the previous match.

Also, you seem to be checking each line in the file individually, which you don't really need to do. You can use `re.findall` to get all the matches in one fell swoop.

And finally `--` at the beginning of the string seems to be your real marker, not `\s` at the beginning or end. So why not just use `--([0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:--)?` with a group around the hex number. `findall` only returns the groups which is what you want. Then you can do this (read the whole html file into one string, and check for all matches):

```
text = """
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkboxKG3" class
--D2CBA65440D
<a>    --77094A27E09--  </a>
  hello world  --77094A27E
--770--
    --77094A27E09
Content-T="checkboxKG" value="KG3" />
"""
import re
hexapattern = r'--([0-9a-fA-F]+)(?:--)?'
print re.findall(hexapattern, text)
>>> ['D2CBA65440D', '77094A27E09', '77094A27E', '770', '77094A27E09']
```

Which I think is what you want