# Sum of hex value in python taking more time

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I've a text file with hex value. i need to calculate "Sum of hex". My piece of code is taking more time when i'm finally calculating the SUM. is there any other way to calculate the sum?? I only want to change the last "for" loop where it is calculating the sum.   file is as follows:

**TEXTFILE**

1. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75173)                | 0x801e4f70 |
2. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75056)                | 0x801e4f90 |
3. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101994)                               | 0x801e4fb2 |
4. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75268)                | 0x801e4fb4 |
5. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74894)                | 0x801e4fec |
6. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101995)                               | 0x801e502a |
7. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75011)                | 0x801e502c |
8. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101996)                               | 0x801e506a |
9. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75095)                | 0x801e506c |
10. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101997)                               | 0x801e50aa |
11. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74830)                | 0x801e50ac |
12. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101998)                               | 0x801e50ee |
13. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75224)                | 0x801e50f0 |
14. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (101999)                               | 0x801e5132 |
15. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (75139)                | 0x801e5134 |
16. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74940)                | 0x801e5184 |
17. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (102000)                               | 0x801e51e6 |
18. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74975)                | 0x801e51e8 |
19. | mpe:pflash0 |                      | .alignment_abcde2345 (102001)                               | 0x801e524a |
20. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74704)                | 0x801e524c |
21. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74939)                | 0x801e52c0 |
22. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74974)                | 0x801e5338 |
23. | mpe:pflash0 | QM_TEXT              | .text.ABC0.abcdefgh.DEFAULT_TEXT_ROM (74892)                | 0x801e53b0 |

## My code is :

```
str2_name = "mpe:pflash0"
lines = []
sumofValue = 0

with open("Text1.txt", 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         if str2_name in line:
            lines.append(line)


def Return_Hexvalue(string):
    Hexvalue =''
    flag = False
    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == '0':
            if string[idx+1] == 'x':
                flag = True
    
        if flag:
            if char == ' ':
                print()
                break
            Hexvalue += char
    
    return Hexvalue
    
for index in range(len(lines)):
    if '0x800a00c0'<=(Return_Hexvalue(lines[index]))<'0x801fffff': 
        sumofValue = sumofValue + int(Return_Hexvalue(lines[index]),16)
        
print(sumofValue)
```

Comment: could you please clarify: you only want to include the hex string in the sum if the line contains `"mpe:pflash0"` and the hex string itself is between `0x800a00c0` and `0x801fffff`?

Comment: yeah right.. @MrFuppes

Answer (score 0):

A `regex` pattern to find the hex strings (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10270407/10197418)) would be nice but since imports are not allowed, here's a way to do without. To improve performance, you can remove the `for` loop that iterates over each line - just use `str.find`. Given that you only have 8 character hex strings, you can use a fixed offset to get the hex string extracted.

```
with open("d:/test.txt", 'r') as f:
    # read the complete file (if it's not extremely large).
    data = f.readlines()

hexes = []
for line in data:
    # check if string is in line
    if "mpe:pflash0" in line:
        hex_idx = line.find('0x')
        # if a hex string is found in the line...
        if hex_idx != -1:
            # add it to the list; we know it always has a length of 8+2 chars
            hexes.append(line[hex_idx:hex_idx+10])

# sum based on condition
s = sum(int(h, 16) for h in hexes if '0x800a00c0'<=h<'0x801fffff')

# s
# 49437821096
```

Comment: this works good but i can't import any module for this calculation this is my limitation.

Comment: @YashK: ok that's a pain ^^ you should add that info to the question though.

Comment: i think i mentioned this "I only want to change the last "for" loop where it is calculating the sum."  but yeahh tht's quite pain..i don't know how to do.

Comment: @YashK ok I changed the code to work without regex. let me know if that helps you.